# visualCode нет кнопки run

Tags: visual-studio-code

Установил VisialStudio Code на Microsoft
прохожу базовое обучение: в ролике человек работает на Mac.
Написал первый код в файле с расширением.JS сохранил, пытаюсь запустить через меню RUN  предлагает запустить с отладкой, во втором случае без отладки. В любом из случаев в выходные данные ничего не выходит, а выходят дополнительные меню. В верхнем правом углу кнопки RUN также нет.
Помогите

Comment: node.js установлен?

Comment: да, установлен  Node.js v18.6.0.

Comment: но node.js  при этом не запущен

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно расширение [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)